# How do I wire a single phase 220v motor with a start capacitor AND a run capacitor, in ADDITION to start windings AND run windings?

Tags: motor, wiring

I speak your language, as I am a 12 year veteran control tech for a boiler company. I'm doing a favor for a friend and ran into this issue. Ive wired plenty of single phase motors with start and run capacitors, but there is nothing in my memory about doing so while utilizing the start and run windings.

I've already identified my pairs, and which is which. I've also identified my capacitors. Unfortunately, there is nothing anywhere online about this, and the older vets I talk to act like I'm stealing business from them or something. We don't use this stuff in my field. The thousands of motors I've wired up over the years are mostly either your 9 lead 3 phase
verity, or your straight forward single phase with a capacitor or 2. My buddy is really counting on me and I'm doing this for free, since he is disabled, and just a really good human being altogether. I'd really like to be able to help him out, and I promise I'm not one who is going to foolishly try to blame some well intentioned electrician for helping me out with advice that I asked for, should things not work out. In other words, I claim all responsibility for this repair, and will not attempt to force, or allow anyone else to share it with me.

If I can't figure it out pretty quickly, I'm literally just going to go buy a viable replacement for him. I've been researching this for over a month now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many motor leads are there? Are they marked or color coded? Does the motor have a rating plate? Can you provide a good picture or otherwise describe what is marked on it. Single phase motors often have information on the inside of the terminal box cover.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this? capacitor start, capacitor run motor:
https://circuitglobe.com/capacitor-start-capacitor-run-motor.html

Any pictures you have will help.

Comment: Mike, this link saved the day. It lead me down the path to my answer, which was this.. A motor with start and run windings IS your standard motor. Nothing unique about it.. So how do you wire a start/run cap motor? The same way I always have! Lol. The terminology is what confused me, since I've actually never worked under a master due to my choice of career, which ddn't require me to. Thus has led yo a few issues over the years regarding overtbinkingand chasing